# How to create column totaling the number of instances of a binary value in R

Tags: r

I'd like to create a new column in my dataframe that adds up the total number of instances that there is a possession, indicated as a "1" in the Possession column, during any given Point. So the count resets any time there is a new point and starts adding up again during that point as soon as there is a possession counted in the possession column.

Any help would be much appreciated. I've tried doing a couple ifelse statements since I'm coming from Excel and don't know what I'm doing but didn't get anywhere.

Starting dataset:

```
df<-data.frame(Point=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
        Possession=c(1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA))
```

Output desired:

```
Point Possession Possessions in Point
1     1          1
1     NA         1
1     1          2
1     NA         2
1     1          3
1     NA         3
1     NA         3
2     1          1
2     NA         1
2     NA         1
2     NA         1
2     1          2
2     NA         2
3     NA         0
3     NA         0
3     1          1
3     NA         1
3     NA         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *base* you can use `ave` in combination with `cumsum` like:

```
df$"Possessions in Point"  <- ave(!is.na(df$Possession), df$Point, FUN=cumsum)
df
#   Point Possession Possessions in Point
#1      1          1                    1
#2      1         NA                    1
#3      1          1                    2
#4      1         NA                    2
#5      1          1                    3
#6      1         NA                    3
#7      1         NA                    3
#8      2          1                    1
#9      2         NA                    1
#10     2         NA                    1
#11     2         NA                    1
#12     2          1                    2
#13     2         NA                    2
#14     3         NA                    0
#15     3         NA                    0
#16     3          1                    1
#17     3         NA                    1
#18     3         NA                    1
```

Or as suggested by @Onyambu:

```
transform(df,"Possessions in Point" = ave(!is.na(Possession),Point,FUN = cumsum))
```

or

```
df$"Possessions in Point"  <- ave(replace(df$Possession, is.na(df$Possession), 0)
                                  , df$Point, FUN=cumsum)
```

or

```
df$"Possessions in Point"  <- ave(ifelse(is.na(df$Possession), 0, df$Possession)
                                  , df$Point, FUN=cumsum)
```

Comment: `transform(df,a = ave(!is.na(Possession),Point,FUN = cumsum))` should suffice

Comment: @Onyambu Oh yes, that much better! Should I include it in the Answer?

Comment: go ahead. Thats why I wrote it here

Answer (score 1):

Base R one liner:

```
df$total_pos <- unlist(sapply(split(df, df$Point), function(x){cumsum(ifelse(is.na(x$Possession), 0, x$Possession))}))
```

Data:

```
    df<-data.frame(Point=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
           Possession=c(1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `dplyr` and the functions `group_by()` as well as `cumsum()`.

It only works if we convert NAs to 0s as cumsum cannot operate on NAs. If that is a problem you could use a different but more complicated solution with a conditional cumsum.

```r
library(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(Point=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
        Possession=c(1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA))

df %>%
  group_by(Point) %>%
  mutate(Possession = case_when(is.na(Possession)~0,TRUE~Possession),Possession_in_Point = cumsum(Possession))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `data.table` package as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, cumsum(nafill(Possession, fill = 0)), by = Point]
```

if you don't find the function `nafill`, you should update `data.table` package.