# Adding a column to a dataframe in R that counts the number of binary observations per unique value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add a column to a dataframe in R that provides counts for the number of times a unique value in one column has a value of 1 in a binary column.  The data is from a study that involved participants listening to sentences and marking syllables that sounded high-pitched.  Here is a sample of the data, with identifiers for ten syllables in `syll` and three participants in `id`.  The columns `id` and `syll` need to be categorical, and `high` needs to be binary/numeric.

```
id  syll high
1   1    0
1   2    0
1   3    1
1   4    0
1   5    0
1   6    0
1   7    0
1   8    0
1   9    0
1   10   0
2   1    0
2   2    1
2   3    1
2   4    0
2   5    1
2   6    1
2   7    0
2   8    0
2   9    0
2   10   0
3   1    0
3   2    1
3   3    0
3   4    0
3   5    0
3   6    0
3   7    0
3   8    0
3   9    0
3   10   0
```

What I would like to do is add a column `high_count` that counts the number of times each syllable was perceived as high-pitched.  For syllable 1 (in `syll`), for instance, none of the three participants (in `id`) marked it as high-pitched (in `high`), so the value in the new column would be 0.  For syllable 2, two of the participants (#2 and #3) marked it as high-pitched, so the value in the new column would be 2.  These `high_count` values need to iterate for each row the unique syllable appears on (i.e., once per participant).  Here is how it should come out looking:

```
id  syll  high  high_count
1   1     0     0
1   2     0     2
1   3     1     2
1   4     0     0
1   5     0     1
1   6     0     1
1   7     0     0
1   8     0     0
1   9     0     0
1   10    0     0
2   1     0     0
2   2     1     2
2   3     1     2
2   4     0     0
2   5     1     1
2   6     1     1
2   7     0     0
2   8     0     0
2   9     0     0
2   10    0     0
3   1     0     0
3   2     1     2
3   3     0     2
3   4     0     0
3   5     0     1
3   6     0     1
3   7     0     0
3   8     0     0
3   9     0     0
```

I have looked at other posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407378/how-to-create-column-totaling-the-number-of-instances-of-a-binary-value-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73828327/how-to-create-a-count-variable-that-counts-based-on-the-value-of-a-binary-variab)) but they don't seem to quite address my situation.

Using this code:

`high_counts <- df %>% count(syll, high=factor(high))`

I was able to get R to summarize the number of 0 and 1 counts for each syllable:

```
   syll    high     n
 1 1       0        30
 2 1       1         8
 3 2       0        15
 4 2       1        23
 5 3       0        29
 6 3       1         9
 7 4       0        36
 8 4       1         2
 9 5       0        33
10 5       1         5
... etc.
```

But I haven't been able to get this into a new column in my dataframe.  I would also only want to keep the "1" values.

Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: take the grouped table, filter it by high==1 and the merge it to the original by the key syll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The columns id and syll need to be categorical, and high needs to be binary/numeric.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df |> mutate(across(-high, as.factor), # note: if, for example, the number of factor levels in the data is larger than the number in the actual dataset (i.e. there are options which haven't been chosen in the data), you can use factor() instead, and set the levels manually.
             high = as.logical(high))
```

To get high_count:

```
mutate(df, high_count = sum(high), .by = syll)
```

To get high_counts as a column:

```
mutate(df, n = n(), .by = c(syll, high))
```

To filter to just ones where high == 1 (i.e. TRUE):

```
filter(df, high)
```

To get a column which shows the total number of high syllables for each syllable, you can do:

```
left_join(df,
          summarise(df, high_count = sum(high), .by = syll))
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you!  I've been able to add a high_count column.  However, on rows where high==0, high_count shows the number of high==0 observations, and when high==1, it shows the number of high==1 observations.  What I want is for every row for a given syllable to show the number of high==1 observations for that syllable, even if high==0 on that particular row.  Do you know how I might do this?  You suggest filtering the dataframe by high, but I still want to keep the rows where high==0.